# Calling external web service from docker container java spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have created a docker container for a springboot application. one of my method in the application calls a webservice (rest api) which is hosted on aws instance.

When the application runs in docker I get `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found` exception.

When the application runs outside docker, it works fine.

I am not sure if there is anything which needs to be set or configured.
Help appreciated.